# Azure APIM validate-content is not validating as expected for JSON

Tags: azure-api-management, json-schema-validator

I had an issue with validate-content policy our API, so for sharing in public
I created a simple Open API Spec yaml file with a schema to create an API and then added validate-content policy. It's validating as expected when a JSON when the right JSON is sent or if I miss any required fields it's preventing with right validation error. However when I send a completely unrelated JSON it's going through fine, expectation is to prevent otherwise it will break the policy expressions.

As suggested in one of the other threads, I also tried adding request representation and specified message schema but behaviour is same.

I also verified it on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/, where validation is as expected

I am not sure it's ignoring as a fact that JSON validation ignores extra elements

Contents of the YAML used

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  title: address-schema-validation
  description: This is a loop back API to test schema validation
  version: '1.0'
  license:
    name: MIT

paths:
  /validate:
    post:
      summary: Submit a request for validation
      operationId: validate
      requestBody:
       content:  
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/AddressBody"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: valid payload
          content:  
            application/json:  
             schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/AddressBody"
components:
  schemas:
    AddressBody:
      type: object
      properties:
        address:
          type: string
          example: "01 Auckland"
        name:
          type: object
          required:
              - fistName
              - lastName
          properties:
            fistName:
              type: string
              example: Fist Name
            lastName:
              type: string
              example: Last Name
```

Policy

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
            <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" />
        </validate-content>
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@(context.Request.Body.As<String>())</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

JSON that picks up the validation error

```
{
    "address": "01 Auckland",
    "name": {
        "fistName1": "Fist Name",
        "lastName": "Last Name"
    }
}
```

with error message

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Body of the request does not conform to the definition which is associated with the content type application/json. Required properties are missing from object: fistName. Line: 6, Position: 5"
}
```

The following JSON is expected to be prevented but it's not

```
{"prevent":"me"}
```

Comment: I just tested this API Spec in IBM App Connect, the behaviour same as Azure APIM :) so this may be expected behaviour, but is there any work around to prevent this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact validation is being done as expected, to prevent unexpected JSON, the schema should have a required root element, if the root element is optional then when completely unrelated JSON is posted the validation policy will simply ignore the unexpected elements.